# Why do we need the kinematic viscosity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, viscosity

Kinematic viscosity is the well known dynamic viscosity divided by density. What difference does it make to divide by density? What is so useful about this?

Comment: It is the diffusion coefficient for momentum transport, i'd say that is a very useful quantity!

Comment: You are really asking well! The truth is that the Mass makes the whole physics "wrong". By dividing the dynamic viscosity with density you get a viscosity unit which has no mass in it. And this provides more practical solutions in all cases, as the calculation goes correct by nature. I share you now even this link; https://www.researchgate.net/publication/294535112_QED_explanation_for_Gravity_and_Radioactivity_Theory_of_Everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the momentum equation:

$$ \frac{\partial \rho u_i}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial \rho u_i u_j}{\partial x_j} = - \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i} + \mu \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} $$

and assume it is constant-density so the $\rho$ can come out of the derivatives, you get:

$$ \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial u_i u_j}{\partial x_j} = - \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i} + \frac{\mu}{\rho} \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} $$

where now $\mu/\rho$ is the kinematic viscosity $\nu$. So, it's helpful when you are looking at constant-density flows, or when you are looking at viscosity per unit mass. It also shows up in Reynolds number:

$$ \text{Re} = \frac{\rho U L}{\mu} = \frac{U L}{\nu}$$

So, it's just convenient sometimes. It may not ever be strictly required, but it helps remove one variable in some cases.